# Can I bring old Dutch cheese to Canada?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, food-and-drink

I've asked the [similar question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34806/can-i-bring-cheese-to-the-us-from-the-netherlands) for the US and the answer was yes. I think it should be a similar situation?

Answer (score 2):

I posted the question without completing a good search (Guilty, to be spoiled by amazing community help).

I found already several links that prove it is possible:

- http://www.inspection.gc.ca/food/information-for-consumers/travellers/what-can-i-bring-into-canada-/eng/1389648337546/1389648516990#a2
- http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/travel-voyage/ifcrc-rpcrc-eng.html#a6